# How to display object with the selected value in dropdown

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, vuejs2, vue-component

I created object like you see in below:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            language: {
                "en": {
                    welcomeMsg: "Welcome to New York City"
                },
                "de": {
                    welcomeMsg: "Wilkommen New York Stadt"
                }
            },
        };
    },
};
```

And I have a dropdown menu, the selected variable in the dropdown menu is "lang".
So when I run this code:

```
<h6 v-for="l in language">
    <div>{{ l.welcomeMsg }}</div>
    <div>{{lang}}</div>
</h6>
```

The display is like this:
Welcome to New York City Wilkommen New York Stadt
en en (selected value is en in the dropdown, therefore it came as "en")

What I am trying to achieve, I want to put if state in h6 tag and I only want to display selected value in the dropdown. For example if 'lang' is 'en', it should display welcomeMsg which is "Welcome to New York City". if it is de, the other one.

Can you help me with this? Do you think I created object wrong?

Comment: ```{{ l.lang.welcomeMsg }}```

Comment: `{{ l[lang].welcomeMsg }}` if you want `lang` to be interpreted as "en" or "de".
But I would recommend to use Vue-i18n (https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply access the language object by the selected value

```
<h6>{{ language[lang]['welcomeMsg'] }}</h6>
```

Watch the demo [here](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion :** Try to use [vue-I18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/) plugin to easily integrates localization features to your Vue.js application.

Working **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sL79nw2m/)** as per OP :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    language: {
      "en": {
        welcomeMsg: "Welcome to New York City"
      },
      "de": {
        welcomeMsg: "Wilkommen New York Stadt"
      }
    },
    selectedLang: '',
    updatedMsg: ''
  },
    methods: {
        updateWelcomeMsg(event) {
                this.updatedMsg = this.language[event.target.value].welcomeMsg;
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<select name="lang" @change="updateWelcomeMsg($event)" v-model="selectedLang">
   <option value="en">EN</option>
   <option value="de">DE</option>
</select>

<div>{{updatedMsg}}</div>
</div>
```